# Python regex using strange unicode characters

Tags: python

The following code does what I want to do:

```
one_sentence = lambda x: re.search(r'b|c|d', x)
```

As as well as the following:

```
if re.search(r'P' + chr(8868), 'aP' + chr(8868)):
    print (True)
```

But I cannot get the following to work:

```
if re.search(chr(8835)|chr(8868)|chr(8869), 'P' + chr(8868)):
    print (True)
```

I'm trying to make it so that if either of `chr(8835)` or `chr(8868)` or `chr(8869)` are in a *string*, then the code prints `True`.

Comment: You need to make the pipes into strings `chr(8835) + '|' + chr(8868) + '|' + chr(8869)`

Comment: To expand on what Peter said, right now the pipe operator is acting as a bitwise OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pipe `|` character to operate in the regular expression it needs to be a part of the pattern string (as you have in the first example `re.search(r'b|c|d', x)`). However, you are using it as a Python operator instead here:

```
>>> re.search(chr(8835)|chr(8868)|chr(8869), 'P' + chr(8868))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Which is why you get an error. The `|` operator is a "bitwise or" and can't be applied to two strings. Instead you need to use strings containing pipes:

```
>>> re.search(chr(8835) + '|' + chr(8868) + '|' + chr(8869), 'P' + chr(8868))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 2), match='⊤'>
```

Or if you'd prefer, you can enter the hex values of the unicode characters straight into the string using the `\uXXXX` syntax, and include the pipes directly:

```
>>> hex(8835)
'0x2283'
>>> hex(8868)
'0x22a4'
>>> hex(8869)
'0x22a5'
>>> 
>>> '\u2283|\u22a4|\u22a5'
'⊃|⊤|⊥'
>>> re.search('\u2283|\u22a4|\u22a5', 'P\u22a4')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 2), match='⊤'>
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that.